# Warnings: In predict.lm prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Tags: r

In my dataset(279 rows and 21 columns) I have missing values and I want to use imputation technique Predictive mean matching in order to predict missing values.

```
my_data_imputation <- irmi(data.frame(my_data))
```

But I get the following warnings:

```
 In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  ... :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

My first idea was to check linear combinations in my dataset and I wanted to use `findLinearCombos(my_data)` but because of the missing values I get an error:

```
Error in qr.default(object) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coer
```

The question is: how can I fix the warnings from the irmi command?

Comment: @李哲源 but can you explain why should I ignore warnings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are duplicates on cross.validated like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it#35077)